# ActionBar tabs with FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(DashboardFragmentActivity.appContext, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
```

Is it possible instead to change Fragment to FragmentActivity? How would you implement this, I'm confuse about those two.

Comment: FragmengActivity is the container for fragments. Why would you want to use FragmentActivities instead?

Comment: I was confuse when I started making my application. And made all my activity ("views"), fragmentactivity. I guess I should have go for fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments are always used in FragmentActivities, so you cannot replace a **Fragment** with a **FragmentActivity**, because nested activities are deprecated.

And you always have an option to use **getActivity();** in the **Fragments** to get the parent Activity, so for whatever reason you wanted to replace **Fragment** with **FragmentActivity** it can be achieved with just **Fragment**.